# WSO2- APIM(1.10.0) Deployment Synchroniser(SVN based) fail to sync new tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have a WSO2 API Manager Setup that works well with SVN when  I use the carbon.super tenant. But when I created a new Tenant and publish a new API at it , the mensage below is showed:

```
*TID[-1234] [AM] [2016-06-23 13:49:43,042] WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl} - Failed to retrieve tags query resource at /repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/queries/tag-summary*
```

After, when I try list all API the error is showed:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-23 13:52:26,393] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error occurred while getting the APIs {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getAllAPIs(AbstractAPIManager.java:303)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getAllAPIs(APIProviderHostObject.java:2685)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor224.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c2._c_anonymous_3(/publisher/modules/api/list.jag:114)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c2.call(/publisher/modules/api/list.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_9(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:34)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.listing.c0._c_anonymous_3(/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag:37)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.listing.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_33(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:232)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_34(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:295)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_33(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:227)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_34(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:292)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_33(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:227)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_53(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/pages/index.jag:17)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c0.call(/publisher/site/pages/index.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/pages/index.jag:10)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c0.call(/publisher/site/pages/index.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c0.call(/publisher/site/pages/index.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c0.exec(/publisher/site/pages/index.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-23 13:52:26,398] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.pages.index:jag} -  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while getting the APIs {JAGGERY.site.pages.index:jag}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-23 13:52:33,634] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-23 13:52:35,775] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-23 13:52:36,633] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error occurred while getting the APIs {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Whe I go to svn, just the tenant 1234 has something. the tenants 1,2,3 is empty.

Comment: Did you configure registry for all the nodes in the cluster properly, as explained below link?

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0

Comment: Yes, I did.  In this setup I have 2 store, 2 publisher, 1 gateway manager, 2 gateway worker and 2 keymanager. Everything works very well using default tenant (carbon.super).

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is not with the deployment synchronizer. What happens is, due to some error occurring when you create and publish the api. I can't get a clue about that failure.

If you go to the gateway manager node's repository/tenants/{tenantID}/synapse-configs/default/api folder, most probably you won't see the api xml there. If so, it means the api didn't get published properly. If the api xml do not reach the gateway management node, it is unable to commit it to the svn. So, this issue is not related to deployment-synchronization.